# How do I locate endpoint of a local folder

Tags: javascript, api, url, endpoint

I am currently learning JavaScript for an online course. For it I have downloaded the backend files that have an API created in them that I'm trying to connect to. I'm trying to connect locally to the /localhost:3000 as that's what my instructor told me to do. However I'm getting an error. Something like this is what I want to run, but with my local URL:

```
const Http = new XMLHttpRequest();
const url='localURL';
Http.open("GET", url);
Http.send();
Http.onreadystatechange=(e)=>{
console.log(Http.responseText)
}
```

I tried typing in the path file name but it didn't work. I guess what I'm trying to do is locate the API in the local folder which I'm struggling to find. Also this is my first time on here. Thanks for being gracious with a newbie!

```
const Http = new XMLHttpRequest();
const url='localURL';
Http.open("GET", url);
Http.send();
Http.onreadystatechange=(e)=>{
console.log(Http.responseText)
}
```

I'm hoping to figure out how to connect to the local URL to get some JSON info back

Comment: Is `localUrl` a placeholder for the actual URL? Or is it supposed to "localhost:3000"? Have you tried accessing this localURL directly from a browser?

Comment: Please share the exact error message your are getting. This info would also help: where is this code located and how are you running it? (For example: "code is in script tag of index.html that I opened with browser" or "code is in index.js of node.js app started from command line" )

Comment: Hi Gino. Yes it is supposed to be localhost:3000 (i was just using localURL as a placeholder).